# ¿De qué manera manejo Ctrl-D (EOF) usando getline()?

Tags: c

¿Cómo puedo manejar **Ctrl-D** (EOF) con `getline()`?

He visto que `getline()` retorna -1 si algo va "mal" incluido que se pulse **Ctrl-D** hasta ahí todo perfecto, pero tengo que distinguir entre un error "normal" y EOF.

Lo que había pensado es que la variable de error errno seguirá siendo 0 si presiono Ctrl-D por que no es un error para el sistema (ya digo que de esto no estoy seguro).

¿Podría detectarlo de esa forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el manual (`man getline`) puedes ver esto:

> Both functions return -1 on failure to read a line (including
>   end-of-file condition). In the event of an error, errno is  set  to 
>   indicate the cause.

Por lo que tendrás que comprobar el contenido de dicha variable. Algunos valores los tienes en el manual (`man errno`), así como la explicación del motivo del valor 0. Puedes consultarlo online aquí:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

> For some system calls and library functions (e.g., getpriority(2)), -1
>   is a valid return on success.  In such cases, a successful return can
>   be distinguished from an error return by setting errno to zero before
>   the call, and then, if the call returns a status that indicates that
>   an error may have occurred, checking to see if errno has a nonzero
>   value.

Si `errno` vale 0 significa que no hubo ningún error, fue un final de archivo (EOF).

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `feof` para saber si has llegado al final del fichero:

```
if( feof(stdin) /* tambien sirve con ficheros */ )
  // el flag EOF está activo
else
  // otro motivo
```

Un saludo

Comment: Hacer una llamada al sistema y comprobar su valor de retorno conlleva una sobrecarga bastante superior a comparar el valor de `errno`, que sería la mejor forma de comprobar si la salida `-1` del `getline` corresponde a una condición de error o a haber alcanzado el fin de archivo (EOF).

Comment: "_Both functions return -1 on failure to read a line (including end-of-file condition).  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate  the cause._". -1 no solo quiere decir que el flag _EOF_ está activo. También deberías plantearte si el rendimiento es un problema en este caso... que salvo que estés usando esta función como si no hubiese un mañana lo mismo el código hasta cumple con las especificaciones y todo.

Comment: "-1 no solo quiere decir que el flag EOF está activo": eso es cierto y no lo he negado en ningún momento, para diferenciar un caso de otro está `errno` tal y como he explicado. Ambas soluciones son igual de válidas, sólo enfaticé la ventaja de una sobre la otra en cuanto a rendimiento.

Comment: El problema que subyace en ese comentario es una tendencia que hay en todo programador de preocuparse por el rendimiento antes de saber siquiera si realmente va a suponer un problema... yo personalmente primero prefiero preocuparme por que el código sea legible y solo cuando el rendimiento debe ser mejorado entonces se empiezan a aplicar optimizaciones. Esto no quiere decir que tu repuesta sea peor que la mía, ni mucho menos. Simplemente son dos opciones diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede testear así, te dejo un simple código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){ // Se puede preguntar si es distinto de EOF sin problemas
        if (c != '\n') // Lo puse para que no te imprima 2 veces la linea de abajo, ya que el '\n' tambien es un caracter
            printf("No es EOF\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```